# Find 2018 with the least amount of numbers

Tags: formation-of-numbers

> Can you assemble a formula using **the least amount of one digit numbers** (from $0$ to $9$) so that the results equals to **2018** with the rules below?

- You may use the operations $x + y$, $x - y$, $x \times y$, $x \div y$, $x!$, $\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}x]{y}$ and $x^y$,
- Using a direct square root is not allowed since it is actually power of $0.5$.
- You may use brackets to clarify order of operations.
- You are allowed to use one digit number as much as you want, such as you may try to assembly a formula using four $2$s two $1$s etc.
- You are **not allowed** to concatenate.
- Double, triple, etc. factorials (n-druple-factorials), such as $4!! = 4 \times 2$ are **not allowed** either.

Comment: Easy. I can use the word form, "two thousand eighteen".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** I can do it using

> $4$ digits

Answer

> $(9\times 5)^2 - 7 = 2018$

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to do it in

> 4 digits as well

Using

> $6^4 + 2 + 6!$

Or:

> $8!/(4\times 5)+2$

Comment: I have edited the $\ast$ to $\times$ (generated by writing `$\times$`). If you disapprove, please let me know.

Comment: If you want, you could write `$\div$` to generate $\div$, but the slash `/` is mostly preferred :)

Answer (score 0):

already solved, but here is another solution

> four digits...    $${9! \over 6!} \times 4+2=2018$$

but this is similar to Excited @Raichu's second answer...

Answer (score 0):

These use more digits than the pre-existing answers do but I think are worth mentioning anyway:

> $$3^7-(6+7)^2$$ $$2^{5+6}-5\times6$$